# deny access from all but accept downloads requests

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have a site for articles applications.

I need to deny all direct access to these files but allow the download on certain pages. These files are .pdf

The location of the files is:
"./public_html/files"

Is there a way to deny all direct access to these files, but allow the download from specific buttons?

Answer (score 2):

You must implement a wrapper on top of your file system and add extra security for this purpose like token.

Let's say your route for downloading is:

`<BASE_URL>/download/{x}`

and `x` is name of the file. This route will only return the file content from `./public_html/files` if user provided a valid token in url like:

`<BASE_URL>/download/{x}?token=diji12jidj`

All of the implementation of this method depends on your needs, e.g. token can be based on user session or based on time or ...

Here is a simple hint in php:

```
// First page
session_start();

$_SESSION['download_key'] = random_string() // a function that you can implement in anyway you want

// In you html
<a href="download.php?name=<FILE_NAME>&download_key=<?= $_SESSION['download_key'] ?>">Download here</a>


// File: download.php
if(isset($_SESSION['download_key']) && $_REQUEST['download_key'] == $_SESSION['download_key']) {
    // find file 
    $path = ... // path to file
    $fp = fopen($path, 'rb');

    // send the right headers
    header("Content-Type: image/png"); // or anything else
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path));

    
    fpassthru($fp);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: How can I do that? Can you send me a video or article about "wrapper on file system"? IDK what is that.

Comment: it's not anything special. What's your backend language?

Comment: Sorry, I'm starting.I'm using PHP.

Comment: Ok. So you must develop a script in php to do it. You can use free file sharing scripts or simply you can develop it yourself. I can't explain all aspects for you but I'll give you a simple solution(not perfect). Check my answer I'll update it